# Always checked checkbox on angular matrial

Tags: angular, angular-material

When clicking, the status of the checkbox changes all the time to the opposite. How to implement a static and unchangeable checkbox on angular material?

```
alwaysCheckStatus(e) {
  e.checked = true;
}
<mat-checkbox (change)="alwaysCheckStatus($event)"></mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: add the code which you have tried

Comment: @Aravind added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `mat-checkbox` inside a `mat-form-field` then it will bind the value of the `checkbox` with the value of the `form` no matter if you add the [checked] property, also make sure that the form value is a `boolean` and not a `string` of "False" or "True".

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the disabled property to true. This is an easy way to disable the double direction data binding of the checkbox.

```
<mat-checkbox [disabled]="true"
              [checked]="someVariable">
</mat-checkbox>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: then checkbox changes color

Comment: Yes, this is a default angular material style when the checkbox is disabled, you can easily override it with css.

Comment: do you suggest removing the class that makes the button inactive?

Comment: FYI; If you will still like the value to be posted with the form I would recommend `readonly` instead of `disabled` as per [web standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled)

Comment: @P.Moloney data need not be sent. Such an attribute does not have angular material

Comment: `readonly` does exist as an angular material input directive, but if you don't need the data it may not be relevant.

Comment: @Nikolay I would recommend not changing the styling of a disabled button as it might confuse your users, but this is a UI/UX issue.

Comment: @Nikolay, for the style I would suggest overriding the class mat-checkbox-disabled in your Host component, or add a new class to your checkbox that adds a style that doesn't seem disabled.